# In C#, is there any way to reduce these 1 List and two Dictionaries to a single collection, possibly using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, collections, refactoring, code-duplication

Currently I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyNamespace{
    using AddFunction = Func<MyDictionary, object, MyDictionary>;

    class MyDictionary {
        public const string AFile = "a.xml";
        public const string BFile = "b.xml";
        public const string CFile = "c.xml";
        public const string DFile = "d.xml";

        private static readonly List<string> fileList = new List<string> { AFile, BFile, CFile, DFile };

        public static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> documentTypeByFileName = new Dictionary<string, Type> {
            {AFile, typeof(ADocument)},
            {BFile, typeof(BDocument)},
            {CFile, typeof(CDocument)},
            {DFile, typeof(DDocument)},
        };

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, AddFunction> functionByFileName = new Dictionary<string, AddFunction> {
                {AFile, (@this, obj) => @this.AddA((A)obj)},
                {BFile, (@this, obj) => @this.AddB((B)obj)},
                {CFile, (@this, obj) => @this.AddC((C)obj)},
                {DFile, (@this, obj) => @this.AddD((D)obj)}
        };

        private Dictionary<string, MyCollection> collectionByWidgetId = new Dictionary<string, MyCollection>();

        public MyDictionary(Dictionary<string, object> dataByFileNames) {
            fileList.ForEach(fileName => this.AddData(fileName, dataByFileNames));
        }  

        private MyDictionary AddData(string fileName, Dictionary<string, object> dataByFileNames) {
            ((DataListable)dataByFileNames[fileName]).GetList()
                .ForEach(item => functionByFileName[fileName](this, item));
            return this;
        }

        private MyDictionary AddA(A a) {
            this.collectionByWidgetId.Add(a.widgetId, new MyCollection(a));
            return this;
        }

        private MyDictionary AddB(B b) {
            this.collectionByWidgetId[b.widgetId].b = b;
            return this;
        }

        private MyDictionary AddC(C c) {
            this.collectionByWidgetId[c.widgetId].cList.Add(c);
            return this;
        }

        private MyDictionary AddD(D d) {
            this.collectionByWidgetId[d.widgetId].dList.Add(d);
            return this;
        }
    }   
}
```

As you can see, it contains 3 different collections.

We need `fileList` to maintain the order.

We need `documentTypeByFileName` to get the type of the C# object which the contents of the files will be mapped to.  Each of these is just a wrapper for a list of a type which can be predicted by the name (e.g., ADocument's contents will be just a List).  So, each of these Document types implements:

```
    interface DataListable {
        List<object> GetList();
    }
```

`documentTypeByFileName` is consumed in another class as follows:

```
        private static Dictionary<string, object> DownloadFiles(IConfigurationRoot config) {
            Dictionary<string, object> dataListByFileNames = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            ShipmentCollectionDictionary.documentTypeByFileName.Keys.ToList()
                .ForEach(name => dataListByFileNames.Add(name, DownloadData(name, config)));
            return dataListByFileNames;
        }

        private static object DownloadData(string name, IConfigurationRoot config) {
            return new XmlSerializer(ShipmentCollectionDictionary.documentTypeByFileName[name], new XmlRootAttribute("Document"))
                .Deserialize(new StringReader(DownloadFromBlobStorage(name, config).ToString()));
        }

        private static CloudBlockBlob DownloadFromBlobStorage(string filetoDownload, IConfigurationRoot config) {
            return CloudStorageAccount.Parse(config["AzureWebJobsStorage"])
                .CreateCloudBlobClient()
                .GetContainerReference(config["BlobStorageContainerName"])
                .GetBlockBlobReference(filetoDownload);
        }
```

We need `functionByFileName` to handle each item from each of these lists.

But, as you can see there is a lot of repeating information here.

Is there a way I can reduce this to a single collection and then be able to manipulate the contents of the collection to avoid all this repetition?

I was thinking about possibily using an `OrderedDictionary` just to remove the List, but it seems that OrderedDictionary would not take parameterized types...

Comment: A [mcve] would be great here. Your current code just doesn't compile.

Comment: I've done my best to put your code together to make it compile, but from what you've given and your description I just don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you please provide a compilable version along with runnable sample data?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I'll need to redact quite a bit more code before I can offer a runable sample, but I'll try to do that in the next several days if nobody else figures it out first.  Till then, I'll add a little more information above.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I do feel you've made it more complicated. You've introduced `MyCollection` and a bunch of other types in your download code. Perhaps just work on making `MyDictionary` compile and then provide some simple Console App code to show how your collection is used?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I was trying to demonstrate how those internal collections I want to consolidate are being used.  The code which will consume `MyDictionary` is not created yet, but ultimately it will be used to combine all the data from the other XML files into a single XML file (which actually won't be the final form of the XML since for some absurd reason [which I can't dissuade him from] the architect  wants to throw XSLT into the mix....)

Comment: I think you should be able to make a fairly small program that will demonstrate the use of your collection. Until I see that I can't suggest an alternative - but I'm thinking that there will definately be one. You're doing some weird stuff in there.